# Changing the case of a single word in a string using Apple Script

Tags: applescript

So I have the Apple Script:

```
-- Uses the satimage osax
-- Get it at http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/downloads/downloads_companion_osaxen.html

tell application "Music"
    try
        set the_tracks to the selection
        repeat with a_track in the_tracks
            set the_old_name to name of a_track as string
            set the_new_name to titlecase the_old_name
            set the name of a_track to the_new_name
            log the_old_name
            log the_new_name
        end repeat
    on error
        set the_tracks to the selection
        repeat with a_track in the_tracks
            set the_old_name to name of a_track as string
            set the_new_name to titlecase the_old_name
            set the name of a_track to the_new_name
            log the_old_name
            log the_new_name
        end repeat
    end try
end tell
```

And I want to be able to change the capitalization of a single element in a string/title. Specifically changing Roman numerals to all caps, in this example finding "Iv." and changing it to "IV.":

from:
Concerto Grosso No. 8 in G Minor, Op. 6, "Christmas Concerto": Iv. Vivace

to: Concerto Grosso No. 8 in G Minor, Op. 6, "Christmas Concerto": IV. Vivace

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Basically it's quite easy to find the roman characters with regular expression but how to prevent Viv in Vivace from being replaced? Or any roman *match* in the name?

Comment: @vadian What I would do is assume that any Roman numeral used will have a '.' after it, such as "IV." Do you have any suggestions as to what the code would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This handler replaces all roman characters from I to IX followed by a period with their uppercase equivalent. It uses the powerful API's from the Foundation framework

```
use AppleScript version "2.5"
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

on uppercaseRomanCharacters(theText)
    set cocoaString to current application's NSString's stringWithString:theText
    set romanRange to cocoaString's rangeOfString:"(I{1,3}|IX|IV|VI{0,3})\\." options:1025
    if romanRange's location < cocoaString's |length|() then
        set substring to cocoaString's substringWithRange:romanRange
        return (cocoaString's stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:romanRange withString:(substring's uppercaseString())) as text
    end if
    return theText
end uppercaseRomanCharacters

set theString to "Concerto Grosso No. 8 in G Minor, Op. 6, \"Christmas Concerto\": iv. Vivace"
set newName to uppercaseRomanCharacters(theString)
```

You can use it in your loop

```
repeat with a_track in the_tracks
    set the_old_name to name of a_track -- as string is redundant
    set the_new_name to my uppercaseRomanCharacters(the_old_name)
    set the name of a_track to the_new_name
    log the_old_name
    log the_new_name
end repeat
```

The handler must be located somewhere on the top level of the script.

Note: 1025 is the integer value for the options `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSRegularExpressionSearch`

Comment: Thanks! In particular I would like to have it loop through each song name in my Apple Music library and apply the edits to the Roman numerals where applicable, with a few edits to this script would I easily be able to do this?